# Button to be clicked and routed to another page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, material-ui

```
 <button component={Link} to={"/create"}>
      <EditIcon></EditIcon>
 </button>
```

This is my code to make an icon a clickable button that routes to the page "create." The button is not performing any function. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Link to={"/create"}
      <EditIcon />
 </Link >
```

and dont forget to import it from react-router-dom

> import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const Button = ()=>{
let history = useHistory();
return(<>
<EditIcon onClick={()=>history.push("/create");}/>
</>

)}
export default Button;
```

here u can learn about react router from this link

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Answer (score 0):

`import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom

const navigate = useNaviagte()

<button onClick={()=>navigate("/create")}>

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).